# Duplicate Results from Batch File

Tags: command-line, batch, script, duplicate

I created a batch file that gives me the ability to input a computer name and it will tell me who is logged into the device as well as the serial number of that device. I pull these two specific bits of information for my job quite a bit so it's very helpful.

The issue I have ran into is more of a cosmetic thing. It's giving me the information but for some reason it's giving me the results twice. The two lines that come back duplicated are:

```
echo User logged on to %computerName% is: %%i

echo Serial number of %computerName% is: %%j
```

Does anyone know why? Could anyone offer some input? Here is the full script.

```
@echo off
:beginning
set /p computerName=Enter the computer name:
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('wmic /node:"%computerName%" computersystem get username') do (
  echo User logged on to %computerName% is: %%i
)

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('wmic /node:"%computerName%" bios get serialnumber') do (
  echo Serial number of %computerName% is: %%j
)

echo.

:menu
echo Choose one of the following options:
echo 1. Run the script again
echo 2. Turn to command prompt

echo.

set /p menuOption=Enter your choice:

if "%menuOption%"=="1" goto start
if "%menuOption%"=="2" goto end

:start
echo.
goto main

:end
cmd /k

:main
goto beginning
```

Comment: Your `for` line is calling the `do` section twice because wmic is giving you two lines.  The second line is nothing but a carriage return.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to remove the blank space that the wmic command is returning?

Comment: On a Linux machine you would append `| head -n 1` to the end of the parenthesis containing wmic. Maybe you can find such a utility.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Try to be more specific by filtering a `wmic` options that return an easier encoding output strings different from the **[UCS-2 LE BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310573/wmic-command-in-batch-outputting-non-utf-8-text-files)** that returns you in the current form/command, something like using `wmic . ... /format:xml`

**2.** Notice that you are making use of a **[System Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)** that has an associated value assignment in **`%COMPUTERNAME%`**, **[change the name of the variable](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**...

**3.** Consider using a different flow in your **[`if %integer% EQU %integer%`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)** condition `goto :label` for there **`goto another :label`**, and this will facilitate the visualization of the flow of possible commands/interactions with the users' choices.

```bath
@echo off

:beginning
set /p "_computerName=Enter the computer name: "

for /f tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in ('
   wmic /node:"%_computerName%" computersystem get username /format:xml^|find "/VALUE"
  ')do echo User logged on to %_computerName% is: %%~i


for /f tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in ('
   wmic /node:"%_computerName%" bios get serialnumber /format:xml^|find "/VALUE"
  ')do echo Serial number of %_computerName% is: %%~i

:menu
echo.
echo Choose one of the following options:
echo 1. Run the script again
echo 2. Turn to command prompt

echo.
set /p "_menuOption=Enter your choice: "

if %_menuOption% equ 2 (
     "%ComSpec%" /d /q /k
    )else if %_menuOption% equ 1 (
     set _computerName=
     goto :beginning
    )else timeout 5 | echo\Invalid choice!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, below are the lines corrected.

I had to add `^| findstr /r /v "^$"`

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('wmic /node:"%computerName%" computersystem get username ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do ( echo User logged on to %computerName% is: %%i ) 

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('wmic /node:"%computerName%" bios get serialnumber ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do ( echo Serial number of %computerName% is: %%j )
```